# Найти количество повторений каждого значения в векторе

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно посчитать количество идентичных чисел в векторе. Вектор состоит из следующих значений

```
0
0
0
31
31
```

Нужно затем сохранить все в одиночный вектор, чтобы выглядело следующим способом

```
vector.x = 0;
vector.y = 3;
vector.x = 31;
vector.y = 2;
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: так чему в итоге равен vector.x? 0 или 31?

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего - использовать `map`:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) a.push_back(rand()%20);
    map<int,int> v;
    for(auto i: a) v[i]++;
    for(auto i: v)
        cout << setw(3) << i.first << setw(10) << i.second << "\n";
}
```

Если очень хочется именно вектор - отсортируйте, и пройдите по нему, собирая одинаковые значения в вектор пар...

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    vector<pair<int,int>> b;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) a.push_back(rand()%20);
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    pair<int,int> p{a[0],1};
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (p.first == a[i]) { p.second++; continue; }
        b.push_back(p);
        p = { a[i], 1 };
    }
    b.push_back(p);
    for(auto i: b)
        cout << setw(3) << i.first << setw(10) << i.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Вектор уже отсортирован . Вот я это и спрашиваю , как собрать одинаковые значения. Но спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Ну смотрите дополненный ответ.